# Concurrent users without database

Tags: node.js, networking, concurrency, socket.io

I can't seem to get this concept right in my head. If I have a website that gets 1 million concurrent users, without any databases at all, will I need to scale? I'm Using Node.js and Socket.IO. Also is there a way I could simulate something like this on my localhost?

Answer (score 0):

Having one million user, or connections, on Socke.io, doesn't mean you have to scale, but depending on what they are doing, you would probably do. Having a data base adds storage but has nothing more to do with the need for scaling the Node.JS server.
You can create a test to try to insert as much as you want using a loop to connect and then try to emit an event for each of then.

Answer (score 0):

For scaling node you can use a cluster. A single instance of Node.js runs in a single thread. To take advantage of multi-core systems, the user will sometimes want to launch a cluster of Node.js processes to handle the load. https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_cluster

To simulate high load, there are open source tools you can use for free: http://www.opensourcetesting.org/category/performance/